# $(\Bbb R \to \Bbb R : x\mapsto x^2)\equiv(\Bbb R \to \Bbb{R}_{\geq 0} : x \mapsto x^2) \not\equiv (\Bbb C \to \Bbb C:x\mapsto x^2)$

Tags: functions, logic, definition

Consider the following functions:
$f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R  : x\mapsto x^2$
$g:\Bbb R \to \Bbb{R}_{\geq 0} : x \mapsto x^2$
$h:\Bbb C \to \Bbb C:x\mapsto x^2$

I'm quite sure that $h$ is not equal to $f$ or $g$, but I'm not sure if $f$ and $g$ are equal or inequal.

If you see $f$ and $g$ as subsets of $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$, then I think both are equal. However, the codomain of $f$ is not the same as the codomain of $g$, therefor you could argue, $f$ and $g$ are not equal. If we would agree that $f=g$, I would not see the point of specifying the codomain.

At university I learned this definition from "[Reading, Writing, and Proving: A Closer Look at Mathematics](http://books.google.nl/books/about/Reading_Writing_and_Proving.html?id=AhVCXPE5yukC&redir_esc=y)":

> A function $f:X\to Y$ is a relation $f$ from $X$ to $Y$ satisfying:
>   i). $\forall x\in X ,\exists y\in Y :(x,y)\in f $
>   ii). $\forall x\in X,\forall y_1,y_2 \in Y : (x,y_1),(x,y_2)\in f\implies y_1=y_2$
>
> An function is often called an map or a mapping. The set is $X$ is
>   called the domain and denoted by $\text{dom}(f)$, and the set $Y$ is
>   called the codomain and denoted by $\text{cod}(f)$. When we know what
>   these two sets are and the two conditions are satisfied, we say that
>   $f$ is a well defined function.

From this definition I would conclude that $f\not=g$. Is this correct ? Are there definitions in mathematics where $f=g$? Can somebody enlighten me a little bit here ?

Comment: I can't even parse the formula you want to be true or false -- I'm not aware of any notation convention that gives a meaning to that mishmash of colons and arrows (_six_ colons in one formula?). Could you try to rewrite it with more standard notation? Or even better, explain _in words_ what you're asking?

Comment: Unless a "relation from $X$ to $Y$" somehow encodes $X$ and especially $Y$, the definition you quote implies that $f=g$. Also it implies that $\operatorname{cod}(f)$ is not defined. So could it be that in your book alread a relation is something like a triple $(X,Y,R)$ with $R\subseteq X\times Y$ and not just as $R$ alone?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Changed it.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I think it would be weird if $f=g$ but $\text{cod}(f)\not =\text{cod}(g)$, right ? This sentence also convinced me that $f\not=g$ in this context: *When we know what these two sets are and the two conditions are satisfied, we say that f is a well defined function.* But I'm not sure. I have my books at uni, so I will look how a relation is specified tomorrow, I don't think it is defined as a triple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you define a function as a set of ordered pairs with a certain property, then $f$ and $g$ are equal. They both have the same ordered pairs.

If you define a function as a triplet of domain, codomain and a graph (which is the set of ordered pairs from the first definition, in many cases), then $f$ and $g$ are not equal because they have different codomains.

In either case, $h$ is different because it has a different domain and different ordered pairs (e.g. the pair $(i,-1)$ is not in $f$ or $g$, or in their graphs as per the second definition).

The former definition is very useful in set theory, the latter is very useful in category theory. Generally, it doesn't *really* matter for the mathematics as long as you understand the fine point of differences and how to go from one form to another when you do need to.

**Also interesting:** [Definition of Function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30381/definition-of-function) (MathOverflow).

Comment: Of course it does matter if one wants to contemplate statements such as "$f$ is surjective".

Comment: @Hagen: Yes, but even in set theory when a function is defined as a set of ordered pairs the statement "$f$ is surjective" has meaning in a non-vacuous way. We simply require *more* context which is provided by defining the codomain explicitly, rather than embedding it into the definition of the function.

Comment: Sorry, I do close to nothing about set theory, but how do you define surjective in set theory if you don't have a codomain ?

Comment: @Kasper: You add context. You don't just say "$f$ is surjective", you say "$f\colon A\to B$ is surjective". Or you say "$f\colon A\to B$ is onto $B$".

Comment: oh of course, I understand.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, in some areas of mathematics, they may talk about "the curve $y=x^2$, and then sometimes talk about "real points on the curve" or "complex points on the curve" and so on.  In that case, I guess the curve itself is not a set of ordered pairs in the sense of your textbook.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that indeed $f \equiv g$ in this situation, because since $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}_{\ge0} \subset \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, then $g\in\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$ also means that $g\in\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$